# When to use Android Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm new to Android development so I don't know the correct coding paradigm. I'm creating a money management app and so far I have one main/launcher activity that runs all of the app's different screens: load, menu, person, etc.

Should I be creating a separate activity for each screen? What's the benefit of using smaller activities within one application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be creating a separate activity for each screen?

At least on phones, probably yes.

> What's the benefit of using smaller activities within one application?

You run out of screen space otherwise.

Now, you may wish to consider organizing your UI into fragments, so that one devices with larger screens, one activity could load up a few fragments, to make best use of the space, while maintaining a "one fragment per activity" model for smaller-screen devices like phones:

[image]